# ¿Como sumar solo las horas transcurridas mientras un formulario (Windows form) se encuentre activo con c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito sumar solo las horas desde una fecha establecida en el siguiente formato:

```
DateTime fechaAntiguaVent = new DateTime(Ano, Mes, Dia, Hrs, Min, Seg);
```

Pero solo sumarlas mientras un formulario se encuentre abierto...

Comment: no entiendo, que quiere decir "mientras un formulario se encuentre abierto" ? como es el input de las fechas?

Comment: Lo que queres es que contabilice tiempo mientras la ventana esta en foco? es muy poco claro lo que planteas

Answer (score 3):

Podrias usar un [stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2).

De esta forma, supongamos que tenes una fecha de inicio que calculas vos.

Al hacer un load del form, podrias inicializar uno de la siguiente forma:

```
Stopwatch Reloj = new Stopwatch();
```

Una vez que hagas eso, cada vez que el form se active, podrias iniciarlo, usando:

```
Reloj.Start();
```

Y cada vez que se desactive, podrias hacer

```
Reloj.Stop();
```

Luego, cuando necesites saber el tiempo, se puede pasar el tiempo transcurrido a un timespan asi:

```
TimeSpan ts = Reloj.Elapsed;
```

Y podrias sumarlo al datetime que ya tenias.

Tu StopWatch deberia estar a nivel del form.

Comment: Gracias gbianchi, era lo que necesitaba.